# Update a certain number inside a string based on the old value of this number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find a number at a certain position and update it (plus another number), for example:

```
const type = 'Dog'; // Can be other types
const qtyOfNew = 3; // Can be other qtys
const str = 'Dog is 5, Cat is 17, Rabbit is 20';
```

Then I want to replace the certain type (Dog in this example) based on the old value (new value will be 5 + 3). After the replacement the str should be:
`Dog is 8, Cat is 17, Rabbit is 20`

This is just an example, the actual format of the string is more complicated and messy. Can I get this?

What I can do is:

```
const reg = new RegExp(type + ' is ' + '\\d+');
const str2 = str.replace(reg, somethingHere)
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is a good opportunity to learn about modules. It will help if you first write a `zoo` module which handles operations on your data. The `zoo.add` function makes it easy to add a new animal or update an existing one. Functions `fromString` and `toString` make it easy to jump between representations -

```js
// zoo.js

const empty = _ =>
  new Map
  
const fromString = (s = "") =>
  new Map
    ( s
        .split(", ")
        .map(_ => _.split(" is "))
        .map(([ k, _ ]) => [ k, Number(_) ])
    )
  
const toString = (t = empty()) =>
  Array.from
    ( t.entries()
    , ([ animal, qty ]) => `${animal} is ${qty}` 
    )
    .join(", ")
  
const add = (t = empty(), a = "", q = 0) =>
  t.has(a)
    ? t.set(a, t.get(a) + q)
    : t.set(a, q)

export { add, empty, fromString, toString }
```

Now we write our `main` module -

```js
// main.js

import { fromString, add, toString } from "./zoo.js"

const input =
  'Dog is 5, Cat is 7, Rabbit is 2'

const result =
  toString(add(fromString(input), "Dog", 3))
  
console.log(result)
```

```
Dog is 8, Cat is 7, Rabbit is 2
```

As we can see, our `zoo` module makes it easy to manage our animal inventory -

```js
// main.js

import { empty, add, toString } from "./zoo.js"

const z =
  empty()

add(z, "dog", 1)
add(z, "cat", 2)
add(z, "rabbit", 3)
add(z, "mouse", 4)
add(z, "dog", 5)
add(z, "rabbit", 6)
  
console.log(toString(z))
```

```
dog is 6, cat is 2, rabbit is 9, mouse is 4
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
// zoo.js
const empty = _ =>
  new Map
  
const fromString = (s = "") =>
  new Map
    ( s
        .split(", ")
        .map(_ => _.split(" is "))
        .map(([ k, _ ]) => [ k, Number(_) ])
    )
  
const toString = (t = empty()) =>
  Array.from
    ( t.entries()
    , ([ animal, qty ]) => `${animal} is ${qty}` 
    )
    .join(", ")
  
const add = (t = empty(), a = "", q = 0) =>
  t.has(a)
    ? t.set(a, t.get(a) + q)
    : t.set(a, q)

// main.js
const input =
  'Dog is 5, Cat is 7, Rabbit is 2'

const result =
  toString(add(fromString(input), "Dog", 3))
  
console.log(result)
```